# call workflow from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have created a workflow project in vs 2010. I have also created a new web application project and then added workflow project as a reference. After this I am trying to call the workflow project using the below code. But the workflow is not running.

`http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/474/leave-management-workflow-using-windows-workflow-foundation.aspx`

```
   WorkFlowActivity.Requestworkflow objWork = new Requestworkflow();
            objWork.requestorleavedata.Add("asdfsadF", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to instantiate workflow runtime for your workflow to run. There is a step by step guide, which can follow to get the basics on how to host and run workflow instance.[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349445(v=vs.85).aspx)